# ngModel doesn't work using primeng table with native checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-ngmodel, primeng-datatable, ngmodel

I'm using primeng editable table with native checkbox and ngModel.

```
<p-table id="resultTable" [columns]="cols" [value]="results" [rowTrackBy]="trackByFunction" 
scrollable="true" selectionMode="single" [selection]="selected" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event.data)">
  ...
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
      ...
      <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rowData.active">
        </div>
      </td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  ...
</p-table>
```

somehow, the [(ngModel)] doesn't work, I can only get the value of `rowData.active`, but when I click the checkbox, the event binding is not working, the value didn't change after clicked.

Dose anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[(ngModel)] is not very stable in multiple situations. Sometimes it works immediately,sometimes it should take some time. The right way to do this is using [(ngModel)] with (ngModelChange)

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rowData.active" (ngModelChange)="fun(rowData)">
```

should notice that:

if (ngModelChange) is in front of [(ngModel)], it will get the value before change, otherwise it will get the changed value

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way using `change` event

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (change)="checkValue(isChecked?'A':'B')" />

checkValue(event: any){
  console.log(event);
 }
```

Here is a code
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e795lx)

Comment: checkbox cannot be clicked after adding (change).

Comment: please check link which i added in ans https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e795lx

Comment: yes, but nothing print out. and important thing is I use checkbox inside of primeng editable table. I tried your way, nothing showed